# Gulp - how to collect images without `dir`and place in one folder?

Tags: gulp

I am trying to collect the only images and placing in to dest folder. my images all are spreads across `bower_components` - so, I am getting no.of folder created. how to prevent this?

here is my code :

```
gulp.task('copy-images', function() {
    return gulp.src('./WebContent/bower_components/**/*.{gif,jpg,png,svg}')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/images')); //creates no.of folders.
});
```

I am getting all images, but all are nested inside of it's parent folders like where it was in original.

Answer (score 0):

use [`gulp-flatten`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten)

e.g.

```
gulp.src('bower_components/**/*.min.js')
  .pipe(flatten())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
```

it will copy all files in a single directory without creating subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gulp.task('copy-images', function () {
   return gulp.src(["./WebContent/bower_components/**/*.*"])
        .pipe(flatten())      
       .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css/images"));
});
```

It would help you